# Empty $_POST and $_FILES, but non empty php://input on multipart/form-data request, iOS AFNetworking library

Tags: php, ios, yii, multipartform-data

I am implementing a multipart request on PHP 5.4 (more specifically, using Yii Framework), where 2 of the parameters are plain text and the other one is an image file. The problem is that if I use the header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, when I do the request, I get the following message

> Internal Server Error
>
> Undefined index: myTextVar1

Using `file_get_contents('php://input')` to check if the server receives the parameters, I can see that all the information has arrived. But both $_POST and $_FILES arrays are empty.

If I remove the header `Content-Type`, request works fine, $_POST and $_FILES arrays are filled properly. I have tried this on Postman Chrome tool, AngularJS and Android, in every case happens the same.

We are using the library AFNetworking on iOS, which automatically adds the Content-Type header, and we would like to stick to it rather than trying to use another solution.

Is there any possible way to fix this on PHP or should we try to use an alternative library on iOS?

**EDIT:** Code of the iOS request

> [sessionManager POST:path parameters:nil
>   constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id formData) {
>
> ```
>         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[myTextVar1 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"myTextVar1"];
>
>         [formData appendPartWithFormData:[myTextVar2 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:@"myTextVar2"];
>
>         [formData appendPartWithFileData:dataToUpload name:@"imageAnswer" fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
>
>     } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
>         successBlock();
>     } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
>         failureBlock();
>     }];
> ```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: `public function actionMyRequest(){
    if (!is_null($_POST["myTextVar1"])){//Already crashes here
    }
}`

Comment: But isn't it logical that content type should be defined? I find fascinating that the request works without setting a content type, but telling the server that is a multipart makes the request fail. Thanks for your answer anyway :)

Comment: @JoseLuisPintado you're only setting the header, to inform the server how to parse the data it receives, however, the actual content (my guess) is formed as url-encoded, so it'll cause an internal server error. Setting just the header is not enough, you also need to format the body using the format set to `Content-Type`.

Comment: @alex-i It seems, the OP has used AFNetworking, which *can* construct multipart messages, where you just specify the input sources. But without code we can only guess. OP: please rephrase your question to make that clear.

Comment: @JoseLuisPintado You are using the function in which you are trying to get the `$_POST` that is not possible. You need to pass the value by reference in which action you are calling the function from there pass the value of this variable.

Comment: Just added the code we are using to perform the request on iOS

Comment: iOS code seems fine (sorry, I thought you manually set the `Content-Type` to something else). To prevent the crash you should use `isset()` instead of `is_null()`, however, this doesn't explain why the parameter is not in `$_POST`.

Comment: Still struggling with this problem, my latest discovery is this one, from Apache error logs
`PHP Warning:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Before leading to confusion, this happens every time i try to replicate the request from postman tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved the problem on iOS by using our own implementation of the multipart POST request, with the help of NSMutableURLRequest. Still this doesn't answer why can't we use AFNetworking or place the Content-Type header on Postman, Android and AngularJS. We have a strong feeling that the issue with AFNetworking is that sends the request chunked (header `transfer-encoding: chunked`). We actually send the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` on our custom iOS implementation, so somehow the problem is not that header at all.

On the server side, when using Postman tool while setting Content-Type header, I can verify that data comes through php://input, but does not reach, php://stdin, $_POST and $_FILES.

We have not tried to disable chunking on Apache, but that might solve the problem too.

I leave below some related links that can be helpful for others in the future...
https://serverfault.com/questions/142512/problem-with-transfer-encoding-chunked-in-apache-2-2/143965#143965

https://serverfault.com/questions/59047/apache-sending-transfer-encoding-chunked

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50210